# How Do I check if an Image is in the request Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

I am working with a service that allows the uploading of images to an S3 bucket, but it is not its only functionality.  I would like to be aware if it is possible to know if an image is coming from the request and know if the image needs to be uploaded or not.  Uploading is not mandatory in this service.

I was thinking in something like:

```
const sendPost = (req,res) => {
  if(req.file) {
    //Upload image
  }
}
```

Well, I don't think it would be like that, but is this possible?

Comment: Please [rewrite your question](/help/how-to-ask) so that people who know nothing about your code get all the details necessary to give an informed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like Mike suggests I am not sure if you just want to know if the file is an image or not. If you need to check the file type, try this library: https://github.com/mscdex/mmmagic

Answer (score 0):

//use express-files and also try

```
if(Boolean(req.files.length)) {
//Upload image
```

}